# Do not re-create session id .net cookieless sessions

Tags: .net, cookies

Due to target audience I am using .net cookieless sessions in auto-detect mode and time to time I get visitors redirected with cookiless session url like

domain.com/(S(jdhdghdghd))/default.aspx

Problem is, if I call this url after session expired .net will re-create it. What I want to find out is a way to force .net to create another session id instead of using the one that came with url.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure the session is re-created? Seems like all session-state would be lost. Do you get a NewSesion event in these cases?

Comment: .net allows me to use same url so i assumed session re-created from the url.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but there is an option in Web.config to disable regeneration of expired session.

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseUri" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false" />
```